# Speed up Solr sort

Tags: performance, sorting, solr

I'm using Solr 7.3 and I notes that when:

- Sorting by **field date** or by **field time** for 100 documents takes 13025ms

`<fieldType name="date" class="solr.DatePointField"  ortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
 <fieldType name="int" class="solr.IntPointField"  omitNorms="true" />`

- Sorting by **score** for 100 documents takes  279ms

Is there any explanation for this. 
How can I optimise that?

I also used Jprofiler, but every think looks normal. 
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: What are the definitions of those fields? Do you have any examples of their content? How many documents are we talking about?

Comment: I just updated my post

Comment: And how about the fields themselves? How many documents are we talking about? Single node or a cluster? Those numbers seem .. way too large

Comment: I do have one core, I indexed 133k documents.

Comment: I note that the  filter Hunspell is the origin of this Slowness.I don't know why but when i comment this filter, both search and index are going well.

Comment: Hunspell isn't very fast as we discovered earlier, but after indexing is done that should be it .. sorting by any of those above shouldn't require another call to hunspell as far as I can tell.

Comment: In my case, I used hunspell in  searching and indexing time, I was thinking that hunspell at searching time takes a lot of hard memory, so that sorting have sifficulties to use it. The problem is that I can't figure out what kind of hard i must increase to increase performance, I'm using CENTOS with 64GO of RAM, I runned JVM with 12GO, I have no symptom of out of memory.

Comment: Throw a profiler at Solr and the JVM and see where it is actually spending its time. There are ways to find out what's happening inside the black box :-)

Comment: I added a screenshot. every I guess it's a normal behaviour.

Comment: You say the core has 133k documents - but you don't indicate the query - my guess is the sort is not the problem but that you have a complex query and not enough memory.

Comment: @kellyfj I found out that the problem was from highlight service.. it takes a long time to parse caracters, so I reduced number of caracters to analyse while highlighting. And response time is acceptable now.